# Как на PHP ещё более кратко написать $x= $y ? $y : $z

Tags: php, тернарный-оператор

Ну сами понимаете, что такое можно не поленится и написать `$x= $y ? $y : $z`

А как насчёт такой штуки:

```
$x=class->SubClass(3,24,5)->SubSubClass(array{'x','y','z'}) 
        ? 
   class->SubClass(3,24,5)->SubSubClass(array{'x','y','z'}) 
        : 
   $z
```

Ну понятно, что можно сделать это:

```
$tmp=class->SubClass(3,24,5)->SubSubClass(array{'x','y','z'})
$x= $tmp ? $tmp : $z
```

Но что-то это всё не то. Хочется как-то так записать:

```
$x= $y OR $z
```

Comment: Собственно можно написать `$x=class->SubClass(3,24,5)->SubSubClass(array{'x','y','z'}); $x = $x ? $x : $z;`

Comment: как на счет этого `!($x=class->SubClass(3,24,5)->SubSubClass(array{'x','y','z'}))  && $x = $z`

Comment: @tutankhamun Опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Цитирую](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Начиная с версии PHP 5.3 также стало возможным не писать среднюю часть тернарного оператора. Выражение expr1 ?: expr3 возвращает expr1 если expr1 имеет значение TRUE, и expr3 в другом случае.

Так что пишите:

```
$x = $y ?: $z
```

Comment: Шикарно! Это  именно то, что нужно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В PHP версии ниже 5.3 можно наиисать так:

```
$x = class->SubClass(3, 24, 5)->SubSubClass(array('x', 'y', 'z'));
$x = $x ? $x : $z;
```

В данном случае не придется дважды вычислять выражение из первой строки